# Double Precision Firebird no PDO

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

Boa tarde, estou fazendo uma consulta em uma tabela do firebird usando o PDO PHP, e em um campo especifico desta tabela esta retornando todos os valores iguais em todos os registros, este campo é do tipo Double Precision.
Será que é algum bug do PDO ?
Alguem já passou por isso ?
Esta me retornando tudo 18.40.
Se eu faço uma consulta via terminal com firebird funciona normalmente.

Comment: Eu nem consegui conectar em um banco Firebird com PDO, acabei usando o ibase e parece funcionar direitinho, só que não lidei com nenhum campo Double Precision nele. Vale testar pra ver no que dá. Segue docs do ibase: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.ibase.php

Comment: Você tem razão, fiz isso é esta tudo certo !